# Having a SQL problem joining two tables together

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to join two tables together by a unique key, but the aggregated numbers are not matching up. My data is attached.

My first table is a transaction report, showing every transaction going on with my account.

My second table is a promotion report, showing promotion and discount given to the orders.

They can be joined by a unique key, which is `amazon-order-id = order-id`.

For some reason, when I join the tables, the sales and fees are wrong. My suspicion is with the join type I use but I tried all the other joins and they still give me the wrong numbers.

[data] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ypoWFXwxP5uvZ4INLzsLLSLhVhBJkyYsjedI1vgBC4/edit?usp=sharing

[code]

```
(SELECT
T1."brand" "Brand"
,DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(T1."date"),MONTH(T1."date"),1) "Date"
,"sku"
,ABS(SUM("selling-fees")) "Referral fee"
,ABS(SUM("fba-fees")) "FBA fee"
,SUM(case when "type"= 'FBA Inventory Fee' and T2."description" not like ('FBA Inventory Storage Fee') then ABS("total") else 0 end) "Inbound shipping fee"
,SUM(case when "type" = 'Refund' then ABS("product-sales") else 0 end) "Refund"
,SUM(case when "type" = 'Deal Fee' then ABS("total") else 0 end) "SC Promotion Deal Fee"
,-(SUM(case when "type" = 'Adjustment' then "total" else 0 end)) "Adjustment"
,SUM(case when "type" IS NULL then ABS("total") else 0 end) "SC Coupon Redemption Fee"
,(SELECT IFNULL(SUM("estimated_monthly_storage_fee"),0) "Storage fee"
FROM "NEW_DATA_WH"."PUBLIC"."STORAGE_REPORT" AS T2
WHERE "T1"."brand" = "T2"."brand"
AND DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR("T1"."date"),MONTH("T1"."date"),1) = DATE_FROM_PARTS("T2"."year","T2"."month",1)) "Storage fee"
,SUM(case when T2."description" LIKE '%... VPC%' then "item-promotion-discount" else 0 end) "SC Coupon Spend"
,SUM(case when T2."description" LIKE ANY ('%S & S%','%Subscribe and Save%') then "item-promotion-discount" else 0 end) "SC Subscribe and Save"
,SUM("item-promotion-discount") "SC Cumulative Promo Spend"
,SUM(case when T2."description" LIKE ANY ('%Free Sub SameDay%','%SameDay US Promotion%','%US Core Free Shipping Promotion%') then "item-promotion-discount" else 0 end) "SC Shipping Promo"
FROM "NEW_DATA_WH"."PUBLIC"."TRANSACTION_REPORT" AS T1
JOIN "NEW_DATA_WH"."PUBLIC"."PROMOTION_REPORT" AS T2
ON T1."order-id" = T2."amazon-order-id"
AND T1."date" = T2."date"
WHERE (T1."type" in ('Order','FBA Inventory Fee','Refund','Deal Fee','Adjustment') OR "type" IS NULL)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: The explanation states that the join condition is `amazon-order-id <> order-id` but the SQL has `T1."order-id" = T2."amazon-order-id"`. Is that a typo in the explanation?

Comment: Please post a sample of expected results.

Comment: @GregPavlik yeah that was a typo

Comment: Please don't link to information that is held elsewhere (nobody who is at all security-conscious is going to click on a random link from someone they don't know) - add all relevant data to your question as editable text

Comment: Without understanding the data, it is difficult to help you with this.  However, you say the join is on `order-id = amazon-order-id` but your query includes `date`.  If this data has returns, credits, or something then is it possible that they don't occur on the same date?  Maybe date should be removed if the ID's are all you need.